# How to maintain hyperledger Fabric participant cards locally for user

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

For the usecase of a market place where users buy and sell stocks, which kind of nodejs architecture for hyperledger-composer should be adopted
for hyperledger Fabric where users dont trust the system. I read many blogs where they said to maintain the cards of user in their
local system.

If i follow UI + Middleware + FabricRuntime. where should the card management be provided and which part/layer should be exposed to user.

Could you please suggest how the design of application must be for such kind of usecases?